# Magento 2.4.1 - Frontend product pages not showing all content

Tags: magento2, porto-theme

I am running Magento 2.4.1 with Porto theme and when accessing any frontend product page, most of the time (not always), not all content is displayed. To see all content I have to manually refresh the individual product page up to 5 times before everything is displayed/loaded.

EDIT: I have also noticed other issues that require refreshing before sometimes working.

On the category pages, the Sort By, Show (12, 24, 36) and view by List/Grid functions are failing most of the time also.

I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: when the content fails to load correctly are you seeing any logged error messages?

Comment: Will be a mixture of caching, elasticsearch bugs and server caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Porto Theme and describe the issues in detailed so that they can assist you shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat as you. Magento 2.4 is riddled with Elasticsearch bugs relating to the Category page (sort by) and search. Best thing to do is to contact Porto and see if they can help, failing that roll back to 2.2 to a somewhat more stable infrastructure until the Mag devs wake up and fix all of the bugs before setting the release live.

Alternatively I have tried this and it seems to work - https://marketplace.magento.com/sparsh-magento-2-advanced-sorting-extension.html

This works with 2.4.1 - Makes the sort by functionality actually work as expected.